# In which files woocommerce saves order data into database

Tags: php, woocommerce

I need to make a woocommerce based system that will take order and it will send the order information to a third party POS system by wsdl. If the POS reply me with success message then i will save the order information into woocommerce database . If the POS reply me with error then i will show custom message to woocommerce user without saving the order info into db .
So i need to know the woocommerce order form action location / file name in where i can write my own code before it saves to db .

Thanks
Md. Muntasir Rahman Rafi

Comment: I am not familiar with woocommerce, I use Shopp. But in general, don't edit core files, you will lose the changes on update. Find filters and hooks to add your feature to the system. A plugin would be best.

Comment: Yes , i have already gather knowledge in maintaining woocommerce by child theme's functions and child theme's woocommerce directory but i need to know in where i can get the order form $_POST data .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , i got solution for my questions . The woocommerce checkout form action is taking at its library class called **class-wc-checkout.php**
In this class there is method named **create_order()**. In this method the woocommerce is taking actions on checkout form submitted data .But woocommerce allow some necessary hook to perform our task .

> "woocommerce_before_checkout_process".

This hook will be called before the order process .Below i am giving sample code .

> function custom_checkout(){
>
> //Your code here
>
> print_r($_POST);
>
> }
>
> add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_process', 'custom_checkout');

Comment: Can you please help me with my problem, i need to get order data (name, email, adress etc) with product data for that order (sku, amount, product name...) so that i can use that data and send it to mine custum REST api, just before the data is saved to database (after order is bought and there is no go back). I am new to word press / woocommerce but i understand that i need to put add_action with custum function in functions.php.

Thanks in advance.